# Jquery Countup Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I was trying to achieve count up timer with this [jquery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

As I am newbie on this, I really don't understand their documentation.

What I want to display is. I want to display counter which counts from 1st January 2005 till current date. Example of output display is

5 years 5months 5hours 5seconds (seconds will be keep counting)

Please kindly help me by posting snippets to achieve. Thanks for your time and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
var sinceYear = new Date('01/01/2005');
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({since: sinceYear});​
```

quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/uwuhe3)

**edit**
more options

```
var sinceYear = new Date('01/01/2005');
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({since: sinceYear,
                                  format: 'YdHMS',
                                  layout:'<b>{yn} {yl},{dn} {dl} and '+ 
                                       '{hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}</b>'});​
```

another quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/uwuhe3/2)

Comment: yes, it is worked. But display is showing like Days Hours Minutes Seconds. What I want to display is Years Month Hours Minutes , instead. Please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the demo also. I can't vote since I don't have enough rep. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ since: new Date(2005, 0, 1) }); 
</script>

<span id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: Hello,  it does not what i am achieving. What I am trying to achieve is using since http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html. And your code get the errors about newYear is undefined and display nothing

Comment: @knightrider - Try this new one

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#since').countdown({ since: new Date(2005, 1 - 1, 1) });
```

You're looking for [`since`](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#since).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">@import "jquery.countdown.css";</style> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var epoch = new Date("1/1/2005");
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#countup").countdown({since: epoch});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="countup">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

code untested. you will need to accommodate the location of the script files yourself.

Comment: yes, it is worked. But display is showing like Days Hours Minutes Seconds. What I want to display is Years Month Hours Minutes , instead. Please kindly help. Thanks.