# Countup Timer with start date as a function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input, countdown

I'm new to javascript and was trying to create a countup timer that could take a certain date as an input and count the time that has passed since that date.

I'm currently using a jquery plugin from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html, but I'm having 2 problems

1) I can't figure out how to add the input date as a function variable. I found another question on this forum that was similar - [Jquery Countup Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778408/jquery-countup-timer), but they were using a fixed date as opposed to a variable input date.

2) How do I ensure that the variable input date conforms to a specific format? Currently I'm trying to read the input date out of a mysql database which timestamps the dates as 
2010-06-17 15:12:30, but I don't think that this is the date format that the jquery plugin will read. Is there a way to parse this date so that the formats match up?

Thanks very much to anyone that can help!

Steve

Comment: Combination of netbrain's answer and my answer will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/HXf5v/

All you need to do is create a javascript function that takes the Date object as a parameter

something like:

```
function doDateCountUp(date){
  $('#sinceCountDown').countdown({since: date, compact:true, format: 'YOWDHMS', description: ''});    
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also always create a jquery function.

```
jQuery.fn.doDateCountUp = function(date){
    $(this).countdown({since: date, compact:true, format: 'YOWDHMS', description: ''});  
}
```

and then you can invoke the jquery function like so:

```
$('#mydiv').doDateCountUp(new Date())
```

---

As for formatting a new Date() object. you should take a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp

which states that you can create a date object like this:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform the mysql date to a javascript date object:

```
function mysql2jsdate(mysqlDate){
   var parts = mysqlDate.replace(/:/g, '-').replace(' ', '-').split("-");
   parts = $.map(parts, function(part){ return parseInt(part, 10) });
   return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var jsDate = mysql2jsdate('2010-06-17 15:12:30');
```

Hope this helps to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taking in the date from a textbox and using it as the startdate:

[countup with input exmample](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmarc/39Uxp/1)

javascript can create a new date by taking in a string in a few different formats.  Here's a quick link to those formats: [javascript date](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference)